# DLL load failed while importing defs

Tags: python, pyinstaller, tensorflow.js, h5py

While compiling a abc.py to abc.exe using pyinstaller i am getting this error.

```
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "tensorflowjs\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "tensorflowjs\converters\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "tensorflowjs\converters\keras_h5_conversion.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "h5py\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "h5py\version.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "h5py\h5.pyx", line 1, in init h5py.h5
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing defs: The specified procedure could not be found.
[21720] Failed to execute script abc
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the above error by using the flag [`--collect-all`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-collect-all).

Usage : pyinstaller --console --collect-all "hyp5" --collect-all "tensorflowjs" --onedir abc.py